# Translating Image Metadata

Tags: aem

What is the best process for handling image data in a multi-lingual site. I understand that the DAM provides basic Dublic Core meta-data fields such as Title and Description, which I was hoping to use for alt-text/captions throughout the site. However, I don't see a way to manage translations without writing [custom Metadata as seen here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/metadata_for_digitalassetmanagement.html) , but this seems wrong on many levels, not least of which is the requirement of overloading `/libs/dam/content/asseteditors` inside of `/apps/` instead of through a jcr:mixinType.

What's even stranger to me is that none of the standard Metadata schemas seem to address translation. I know that I can provide a Title/Description via the Image Component properties, but it seems incorrect to decouple this descriptive information from the Asset itself, forcing content Authors to add a title on each occurrence of the asset. At the very least, I would think that the Image Component could default to the DAM properties, but provide the option to override them as needed.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is using Metadata to store image "content" a misuse of the standard?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to upgrade to AEM 6.1, if you haven't already done that. Multi lingual Support is OOTB! 
Please see the documentation:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/projects/language-copy.html